# Does to correct someone mean to correct his grammatical faults?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

If some one is speaking and making some grammatical mistakes, and we want to ask him if it's okay to correct his grammatical mistakes, can we ask him like this:

**"Is it okay to correct you?"**?

or we have to say:

**"Is it okay to correct your mistakes?"**?

, or both of them are right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "correct you" and "correct your mistakes" have the same meaning.

However, both your sentences are ambiguous, since they could refer to factual mistakes instead of grammatical mistakes.  To be more specific you could ask:

> Is it okay to correct your grammar?